# Tensorflow image evaluation one on channel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, rgb

I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend and want to evaluate the PSNR between two images. I am able to evaluate on all three RGB channels, like this:

```
def psnr(hr, sr):
    return tf.image.psnr(hr, sr, max_val=255)
```

with the psnr function from tensorflow ([tf.image.psnr](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/psnr)

But what would I do to only evaluate on the first channel? I assume I need to extract those values from the tensor some how. In python it is usually possible to do something like hr[:, 0, 0], but this obviously does not work here.

Answer (score 1):

```
im1 = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(np.random.randn(64,64,3), tf.float32)
im2 = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(np.random.randn(64,64,3), tf.float32)

psnr = tf.image.psnr(tf.expand_dims(im1[:,:,0], 2), 
                     tf.expand_dims(im2[:,:,0], 2), max_val=255)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(psnr))
```

Get the first channel using `im1[:,:,0]` and reshape it to `h x w x 1` by adding the one channel using `expand_dims`